# Printing the first character in a given string which does not repeat

Tags: c++, string, pointers

I am using the following function in c++ to return the first character in a given string which does not repeat,if not found return '@'.

```
char MyMethod(const char* str, int len){
    int i,index=-1;
    int *count = new int[256];

    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
       count[*(str+i)]=0;
    }

    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
       count[*(str+i)]++;
    }

    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        if(count[*(str+i)]==1)
        {
            index=i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(index==-1)
        return '@';
    else
        return *(str+index);
}
```

this method looks fine, but it is always returning the first character of the string.
for example for the following string

```
aabcdd
```

it returns 'a' instead of 'b'.

Comment: May want to plug that memory leak when you fix this, btw.

Comment: @Levi the first for loop setting all elements to zero, second to count the frequencies in an array and third to check the first non repeating character

Comment: Side note: replace `int *count = new int[256]` with `int count[256]`. No need to allocate it dynamically (certainly when you're not bothering to deallocate it at the end). BTW, A more standard way to make use of the constant value `256` in the context of this code, would be to include `limits.h` and use `1<<CHAR_BIT` instead.

Comment: @barakmanos thanx using dynamic allocation was of no use, but still code not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there has been a typo.
The statement :

```
 if(count[*(str+i)]==1);
```

should not have been terminated:

```
 if(count[*(str+i)]==1)
```

Remove the semicolon, so that the statements after the `if` condition are evaluated only when the condition is true.
Otherwise, the statements will be evaluated whatever be the result of `if`.

Comment: @karma_geek..I have removed the semicolon but it is not giving first non repeated character

Comment: @ karma_geek I have checked this cout<<MyMethod("zsdfhogfmpsdfgohfghz",19); in your link   but it is giving 'z' instead of 'm'

Comment: @toadalskiii: That is because your string has 20 characters, not 19! Try `cout<<MyMethod("zsdfhogfmpsdfgohfghz",20);` instead. This gives you `m`.

Comment: yup it works correctly in the ideone.com but in my compiler it is not showing correct character. Don't know why?

Comment: @toadalskiii: you sure you have the same code on both?

Comment: For debugging I had commented break in the if condition but forgot to remove, now works like a charm. Thanx :)